# Use custom configuration file for CKEditor in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, angular2-template, ckeditor4.x

I want to use my own configuration file for CKEditor, **in Angular 2**.

While doing this

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
            customConfig: '../../admin/app/js/scripts/ck-editor-config.js',
            extraPlugins: 'colorbutton,colordialog,embed'
});

CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

But how can I get the instance of `CKEDITOR` in my component?

I have integrated CKEditor in my Angular 2 project, but I want to change the config file, I want to add my own custom config. Please suggest me what I can do? I don't have the instance of CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

After too many explorations, I got it:

**Use in HTML:**

```
  <div>
       <ckeditor 
                 formControlName="contentBody" 
                 [(ngModel)]="content.contentBody" 
                 [config]="{uiColor: ''}" 
                 [readonly]="false" 
                 debounce="500">
       </ckeditor>
  </div>
```

Add below the line of code into your `component` in which you are using this `CKEditor`.

**Import `CKEditorModule` & `CKEditorComponent` into your component:**

```
import { CKEditorModule, CKEditorComponent } from 'ng2-ckeditor';
```

**Create a default content:**

```
  this.ckeditorContent = `<p>My HTML</p>`;
```

Now you can write your **CKEditor's configuration** in `ngAfterViewChecked()` hook in your `component`:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {

    if (this.contentForm.value.type == 'Html') {


      let editor = this.ckEditor.instance;

      editor.config.height = 200;

      // editor.config.toolbar = [
      //   // { name: 'document', items: ['Source', 'Templates'] },
      //   { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] }, '/',
      //   { name: 'insert', items: ['Image'] },
      //   { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
      //   // { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat'] }
      // ]

      editor.config.toolbar =[
          ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ];

      editor.config.removeButtons = 'Templates,Find,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Form,Radio';

      editor.config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font,Undo,Redo';


    }

  }
```